# Compiler.complieClass Returns false (java.lang.Compiler)

Tags: java, android, compiler-construction, jit

The purpose of the code here is to compile a class that was created on a .java file so that it could tell if the users input was correct. However the code returns false with every trial.
    import java.lang.*;

```
/**

* @author Joey
 */
public class NewCompTets {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

     NewCompTets cls = new NewCompTets();
     NewCompTets subcls = new SubClass1();

     // class CompilerDemo
     Class c = cls.getClass(); 
     System.out.println(c);

     // sub class SubClass1
     Class c1 = subcls.getClass();
     System.out.println(c1);

     /* returns false if the compilation failed or no compiler is 
     available */
     boolean retval = Compiler.compileClass(c1);

     System.out.println("Return Value = " + retval); 
   }
} 

class SubClass1 extends NewCompTets {
   public static void test(){
       System.out.print("2");
   }
}
```

Comment: Do you know if a compiler is available in the first place?

Comment: JIT compiler in android is available from 2.2. What android version you have?

Comment: I have no idea if the compiler is available but that might be my issue.

Comment: Might want to check that first. If the compiler is available, I'd look to see if it's possible to get an error message from it, but after a quick look at the API it might be somewhat difficult...

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you always need to compile the parent class first, then you can compile the child classent class then you can compile the child class.